# Asus zenfone 5 how to bypass flipcover screen without flipcover

Tags: factory-reset, asus-zenfone-5

Recently I got an asus zenfone 5 which is stuck on flip lock screen.
I want to bypass that screen without using flip cover.
Is there any way that i can bypass it without using a flip cover.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I solved just with a magnet on the left bottom side of my zenfone 3.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to bypass it by covering the sensor on top of the screen by hand and by that i was able to enter to settings and disable the settings. Hope this will help you.

This is not a sure shot solution I think I just got lucky.

Answer (score -1):

This [thread](http://www.asus.com/zentalk/forum.php?mod=viewthread&tid=4697&extra=page%3D1&page=2&mobile=2) on the Asus forum may help.

Comment: It Did not help But thanks for answering

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Please do the needful and that's probably the reason why it was down voted. Ping me once done. Thanks

Comment: Wow, that not-an-answer of mine :D I was so innocent  2 years ago  :D